# Produce a Query viewing multiple tables

Tags: sql, task

I have been given a database, the structure and data values are all unchangable and have been provided with a question.

Produce a query to list the holiday code, holiday description, holiday duration and site description for all holidays which visit site code 101. Your answer must not assume that site code 101 will always have the same site description.

I am confused on how to tackle this question. I have tried Multiple joins, different dot notation and googled the question to hell and back. Any help?

Table 1 - Holiday_Details

Holiday_Code - Country_Visited - Holiday_Duration - Holiday_Desc - Rating_Code - Cost

Table 2 - Site_Of_Holiday

Site_Description - Site_Code

Table 3 - Site_Visited

Holiday_Code - Site_Code

Comments have asked for previous attempts. This was my first.

```
SELECT holiday_code, 
       holiday_desc, 
       holiday_duration site_of_holiday.Site_Name 
FROM   holiday_details 
       JOIN site_visited 
         ON holiday_code = site_visited.holiday_code 
       JOIN site_of_holiday 
         ON site_visited.site_code = site_of_holiday.site_code 
WHERE  site_of_holiday.site_code = 101;
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried that did not work. For an assignment/interview question such as this we are happy to help you out where you are stuck, with specific evidence of previous effort. We generally won't provide complete answers though.

Comment: Yes it is homework, but as michael said, I will provide one of my previous attempts. I just cannot fathom how to tackle this question due to the structure of the tables we have been provided.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, you'll get a better response if you post a lot more detail about your failed attempts.  By that, I mean code.  Using SO to solve your homework assignments is frowned upon but, like a commenter said, once you've wracked your brain we're willing to help.

You seem like you may have actually tried real hard, so I'll throw you a bone...

The trick to navigating multiple tables is to find the "pairs" of matching columns.  In this case you want to find a path between the tables Site_Of_Holiday (which has Site_Description) and Holiday_Details (which has everything else).

The columns that match between each pair of tables are:

- Holiday_Code is found in both Site_Visited and Holiday_Details
- Site_Code is found in both Site_Of_Holiday and Site_Visited

This allows you to build a path between the tables that contain all of the columns we want in the output.  You would do this, in this case, using INNER JOINs across those matching column pairs.

Once you've joined the tables, think of the result like a giant table whose columns include all columns from all three tables (prefixed with whatever you 'name' the table during the joins).  Now you just filter on the Site_Code with the usual WHERE clause.

Here's the full example - let me know if it works for you:

```
SELECT hd.Holiday_Code, hd.Holiday_Desc, hd.Holiday_Duration, soh.Site_Description
FROM Holiday_Details hd
INNER JOIN Site_Visited sv ON hd.Holiday_Code = sv.Holiday_Code
INNER JOIN Site_Of_Holiday soh ON sv.Site_Code = soh.Site_Code
WHERE sv.Site_Code = 101
```

Good luck!

P.S. In case any Americans get a similar assignment, here's the translation ;-)

```
SELECT vd.Vacation_Code, vd.Vacation_Desc, vd.Vacation_Duration, sov.Site_Description
FROM Vacation_Details vd
INNER JOIN Site_Visited sv ON vd.Vacation_Code = sv.Vacation_Code
INNER JOIN Site_Of_Vacation sov ON sv.Site_Code = sov.Site_Code
WHERE sv.Site_Code = 101
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have sat here for about 2 hours trying to figure out how to tackle this question. Using google and youtube provided help but no full information that is fully related to my attempt, or even relevant. I would have been happy just with the first part, but the example will probably help me even more. I will post with the results :D